# Pass URL parameter (utm code) across my site's webpages

Tags: php, tracking, utm

I have a webpage I'm trying to promote via ad banners. I want to associate a utm code to those those links, so when a visitor lands on my website, I'll be able to track where they came from (mysite.com?utm_campaign=adXYZ)

Normally these ad banners lead to a single webpage with single point of conversion where I'm able to capture the utm_campaign ID and gauge how effective my marketing is. However, I'm now leading users to a full website with many pages and many points of conversion. I'm hoping to keep that utm_campaign ID across multiple pages using some crafty JS or PHP.

For example:

1. user clicks ad banner to mysite.com?utm_campaign=adXYZ
2. user lands on mysite.com but wants to go to mysite.com/features
3. user goes from mysite.com/features to mysite.com/pricing
4. **By the time the user reaches mysite.com/pricing, I want ?utm_campaign=adXYZ to still be there in the URL.**

I know there are ways via analytics and what not to track a session/conversion, but I specifically need to capture the referral utm code in an HTML form down the road. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a bunch!

**Edit: An important point to note.** The site should still be accessible organically via search, bookmark, linking, etc and not have the trailing campaign ID in the URL. Only when user visits the site from ad banner should the campaign be there and all subsequent pages.

Answer (score 3):

I would set a **cookie** containing the relevenat information the first time the user enters your website.

Otherwise you have to pass the information every time again with every request (**GET / POST**). This solution will work even if the user don't allow cookies. Murat Cem YALIN wrote how this works in detail. But if you want to use the JS-method: Be aware that the user must have JS activated!

The third option might be using **PHP Sessions**.

Comment: This. Also: what if a user copies the address at some point and passes it to his friend. They'd also have the `utm_campaign` param, even that doesn't apply to them.

Comment: But then the campain-code should change (because the friend discovered the website not by clicking the banner)?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with both php and js. 
in php use simplehtmldom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to access all links in html output and add ?utm_campaign=adXYZ to all of them just before outputting rendered html.
in js you use jquery to do the same when the document loaded. ex:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + '?utm_source=adxYZ');
});
```